# SonarQube, how do to analyze a package instead of a file?

Tags: file, sonarqube, package

I am requiring to analyze roughly 50 java files, and do not want to analyze them one by one when editing the configuration file. How do I enter in a directory, and it automatically detects all the java files in the directory and perform code analysis on all the java files?

Edit:

The components I have added to the configuration file is :

```
sonar.projectKey=three
sonar.projectName=three
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources = C:/Users/x/Desktop/project/projectY/projectZ/src
sonar.inclusions = C:/Users/x/Desktop/project/projectY/projectZ/src/**/*.java
```

Inside src are two directories, and inside those sub directories further down contain all the java files I want to analyze. Windows 10 62bit os.

It is recognizing 39 files, but it says it is ignored.

```
0 files indexed

39 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

Comment: you mean you are looking for wildcards like src/com/foo/bla/**/*.java ?

Comment: maybe you should also post your configuration you have right now -> it seems like you at least know some parts, and might just be wrong with  a minor configuration. Update your question, representing your configuration. else it will be hard for anybody to really help you. the only thing we can point you to right now is the sonarqube docs

Comment: how do you analyse your project? CLI, Gradle, Maven, and where do you start the scanner, do you really need absolute paths?

Comment: I analyze my project by using a scanner and adding to the configuration file. Then open the local server and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

there is one simple answer: Read the docs -> sonarqube is pretty well documented

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

`sonar.inclusions` is the property you are looking for, and how you can work with patterns, is explained in the docs.

```
sonar.inclusions=src/net/something/**/*.java
```

Comment: Why is it mandatory do also help sonar.sources = ... then, this should overwrite where the source files are coming from?

Comment: It is also still saying the files are ignored, despite me trying both * and *.java from the used directory